# What is the recommended method for marinating the sea bass before grilling in the Flavorful Grilled Sea Bass with Tangy Chili-Lime Dressing Recipe?

Tags: flavor, seafood

What is the recommended method for marinating the sea bass before grilling in [this Flavorful Grilled Sea Bass with Tangy Chili-Lime Dressing Recipe](https://www.facebook.com/groups/377794221601436/permalink/379013928146132/)?

Recipe follows:

Flavorful Grilled Sea Bass with Tangy Chili-Lime Dressing Recipe
*Ingredients:*
4 sea bass fillets
2 tablespoons olive oil
Salt and pepper to taste
1 lime, juiced
1 tablespoon chili powder
2 tablespoons honey
1 clove garlic, minced
1 small red chili, finely chopped
2 tablespoons fresh cilantro, chopped

*Directions:*
Preheat grill for medium heat and lightly oil the grate.
Brush sea bass fillets with olive oil and season with salt and pepper.
Grill sea bass for 3-4 minutes per side, or until fish flakes easily with a fork.
In a small bowl, whisk together lime juice, chili powder, honey, garlic, and chopped chili.
Drizzle the chili-lime dressing over grilled sea bass and garnish with chopped cilantro.

Comment: Hey, I removed your anonymous 3rd party link and replaced it with the actual link.  Please don't use link shorterners, since we can't tell that they're not spam.  Also, I pasted in the recipe since it's on a site that requires a login.

Comment: Eek! That's a lot of honey. Hope you like sweet & sweet & sour ;)

Answer (score 1):

According the the recipe, there is no marination step.  Grill the fish and then drizzle with the dressing.  Beyond that, keep in mind that marination is a surface treatment, but with fish, any acidic marinade will denature the proteins over a relatively short amount of time. So, in this case, I can see why a dressing is called for, rather than a marinade.